# onDeviceready(), called twice on meteor.startup() of client side

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I deployed meteor app on galaxy server,then built an app using my cloud server address and installed it on mobile.But when I open the app onDeviceReady() is calling twice,but it should happen only once.Can anyone suggest me the reason?
My code at client side is as follows:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log("inside start up client");
    $.Finger = {
      pressDuration: 2000,
      doubvarapInterval: 300,
      motionThreshold: 5
    };
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
      function onDeviceReady () {
        alert("Calling onDeviceReady()");
        Push.Configure({
          android: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
            vibrate: true,
            clearNotifications: true
          },
          ios: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
          }
        });
        Push.addListener("token", function(token) {
          console.log("push notification listened",token);
          Session.set("myToken",token);
        });
      }
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady,
          false) }, 1000);
    }
  });
}
```

The cordova-plugins which I am using are:

```
cordova-plugin-device@1.1.5
cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@1.6.0
phonegap-plugin-push@1.5.2
```